# didSelectRowAt indexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I created a UIViewController that contains two View (Top , Bottom),
the Bottom view expands all the way to the top when clicking on the searchBar. (bottomView height expands, topView height is getting smaller).

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.expandBottomView()
    return true
}

func expandBottomView() {
    let heightToAdd = TopView.frame.height - numOfRequestsTitle.frame.height

    RecomandFriendHeight.constant += heightToAdd
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    topTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Both View contain TableViews (topTableView , BottomTableView) all delegates are set I checked.
BottomView Contains another button to collapse the bottomView when needed.

topTableViewCell contains two Buttons and two labels.
bottomTableViewCell contains a label and an imageView.

The Problem is none of the tableViews cells invokes didSelectRowAt.
[image]

Comment: To what class is the delegates set to?

Comment: to the UIViewController that contains the topView and bottomView.

Comment: can you provide more code?, I would like to see the delegates and data source being set for both tableViews and also the didSelectRowAt method declaration.

Comment: Try debugging using the following techniques: 1. Try to capture the view hierarchy and check if the tableView is tappable. 2. Make sure userInteraction is enabled when required, since you are disabling it.

Comment: isn't it because you are not actually clicking the "cell" but the elements in the cell, its probably blocked by label or something. Debug your view Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If you add button to a cell didSelectAt not called on tapping the button. In this case you have to add a selector to this button inside cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customcell
        cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickedCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

  }
```

and implement this selector method

```
func clickedCell(_ sender : UIButton) {
        print("clicked")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make
   `topTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`